# how to simplify symbolic integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following is the code:

```
    In[3]:= Simplify[Integrate[f[x]*c, {x, a, b}]/c, Assumptions -> c > 0]

    Integrate[c f[x], {x, a, b}]
    ----------------------------
                c
```

but obviously the right answer should be:

```
    Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]
```

how to solve it without placing c outside the integrate function?

Comment: how about Simplify[Integrate[f[x]*c, {x, a, b}]/c/. Integrate-> int]/. int-> Integrate?

Comment: the same problem.

Comment: @chris If you first define `int[c_Symbol*f_, dom_] := c*int[f, dom]` or some such, then that should work fine.

Comment: yes,it works,but we may need more code to take out the variable from the expression.

Comment: @howard *What* expression??

Comment: @Mark McClure right. Thanks !

Comment: Simplify[Integrate[f[x]*c*Exp[c]*c, {x, a, b}]/c /. 
   Integrate -> int] /. int -> Integrate

Comment: @ Mark McClure, I see,Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can tell Mathematica that it may move multiplicative constants out of the  integral by defining the function

```
moveconst[x_]:=(x /.
  Integrate[factor_ expr_, {var_, min_, max_}] /; FreeQ[factor, var] :>
  factor Integrate[expr, {var, min, max}])
```

and then using

```
Simplify[Integrate[f[x]*c, {x, a, b}]/c, Assumptions -> c > 0,
         TransformationFunctions->{Automatic, moveconst}]
(*
==> Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]
*)
```

Note that Mathematica only uses the transformation if it really makes the expression simpler:

```
Simplify[Integrate[f[x]*c, {x, a, b}], Assumptions -> c > 0,
         TransformationFunctions->{Automatic, moveconst}]
(*
==> Integrate[c f[x], {x, a, b}]
*)
```

Here, moving the constant out of the integral would not have simplified the expression, therefore Mathematica doesn't do it.

Comment: @ celtschk,Thanks! problem solved.

Answer (score 33):

**Edit for *Mathematica* version 9 and higher**

To make this answer work with definite integrals in versions greater than 8, I added the line with `SetAttributes` in the definition below. Without declaring the antiderivative `ff` as a `NumericFunction`, the simplifications that were done in version 8 don't kick in, and the expressions remain unevaluated.

**End edit**

There is no way to do *exactly* what you want because an assumption can't be used to tell Mathematica that there exists an indefinite integral of the unknown function `f[x]`. See for example [this MathGroup post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/jsiYo9tRj04/rQYCy-X3SXQJ).

However, you can get *almost* what you need if you define the indefinite integral yourself in the following way:

```
f /: Integrate[f[x_], x_] := ff[x]
SetAttributes[ff, {NumericFunction}]
```

This declares `ff[x]` as the anti-derivative of `f[x]`. Now we can get somewhere with the symbolic integration:

```
Simplify[Integrate[c f[x], {x, a, b}]/c]
```

> `-ff[a] + ff[b]`

By using the delayed assignment (`TagSetDelayed`) for the indefinite integral, it's also possible to use other integration variables, as in

```
Simplify[Integrate[c f[t], {t, a, b}]/c]
```

> `-ff[a] + ff[b]`

**Edit**

The advantage of this approach is that it also helps with other simplifications whose pattern *you may not have foreseen* at the outset. If you follow the pattern-matching micromanagement approach of the other answers, you'd have to introduce new patterns for new cases. For example, I can also simplify the integral:

```
Simplify[Integrate[c + f[x], {x, a, b}]]
```

> `(-a + b) c - ff[a] + ff[b]`

And one could go on...

Comment: very good! Thank you!

Comment: This seemed the most mathematically kosher way to deal with the situation. But I just noticed I should make the indefinite integral independent of the variable name `x`. I'll modify my answer by using a `TagSetDelayed` instead of `TagSet`.

Comment: Very nice! I used your solution here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9683/193, with due credit.

Comment: I tried this in V9 and V10 and it didn't do anything. Can you please confirm that it still works?

Comment: @Pickett It definitely works in version 8 which I still use for serious work. Version 10 seems to be mainly thrown out there to get a lot of free beta testers. But I'll look into it later.

Comment: @Jens I suspected that you were using V8, no worries if it doesn't work in later versions it was just out of interest as I didn't see anything version specific in the code. Thanks for checking it.

Comment: @Pickett Thanks for letting me know, anyway - maybe I'll report it as a bug - finding out that old code no longer works seems one of the constant battles in Mathematica. But I've had worse (recalling version 5 -> 6 and then again 6 -> 7)...

Comment: @Picket I've submitted a bug report[CASE:1477670], but I figured out a fix, see my edit.

Comment: Nice! That works.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite probably ill-advised, but

```
Clear[mysimp];
mysimp[Integrate[c_Symbol*f_[x_], {x_, a_, b_}]] := 
  c*Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}];
mysimp[h_[x__]] := Map[mysimp, h[x]];
mysimp[x_?AtomQ] := x;
mysimp[Integrate[c*f[x], {x, a, b}]/c] // InputForm
```

Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]

These patterns are written quite specifically for your example, though.  I don't expect this to be generally useful.

Comment: ok,good,thank you!