# How to simplify the integration result of the following program?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In the following program, the `fec[x]` is a function depending on $x$ while `q3[t]` and `q5[t]` are functions depending on $t$. Now, I want to use `Integrate` for the polynomial which is composed by `fec[x]`, `q3[t]`, `q5[t]`, et al. for the independent variable $x$.  I believe the result `c` is zero, but I don' t know why the software could not convert it to zero automatically. Could you help me?

```
inta = Cos[q3[t]] fec[x] q5[t]^2 D[q3[t], t]^2;
a = Integrate[inta, {x, 0, L1}];

b1 = Cos[q3[t]] q5[t]^2 D[q3[t], t]^2;
b = Integrate[fec[x], {x, 0, L1}] b1;

c = a - b;
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, SunnySky! Let me remind you three things we 
usually do here: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering 
questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)! 
3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), 
because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users 
sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves 
your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 7):

The problem can be distilled to a much simpler form to help illustrate what is going on. (whenever you find a problem, try to find the most simple form that shows the problem)

It has to do with definite vs. indefinite integration.

```
Clear[q, x, L1]
Integrate[q[x]*f[t], x]

Out[52]= f[t]*Integrate[q[x], x]
```

You see that now it pulled the function that does not depend on the integration variable out.

Do the same, now using definite integration

```
Clear[q, x, L1]
Integrate[q[x]*f[t], {x, 0, L1}]

Out[54]= Integrate[f[t]*q[x], {x, 0, L1}]
```

You see, the `f[t]` remained inside. I am not a math guy, so can't explain why it does not remove  `f[t]` out when it is a definite integration. But it looks like when it is definite integration, you need to tell it that those functions that explicitly depend on `t` and not `x` remain independent of `x` for the definite case. I do not know how to do this.

That is why this gives zero

```
Integrate[q[x]*f[t], x]-f[t]Integrate[q[x], x]
Out[55]= 0
```

while the definite version does not (which is what you are basically asking)

```
Integrate[q[x]*f[t], {x, 0, L1}] - f[t]*Integrate[q[x], {x, 0, L1}]
Out[56]= (-f[t])*Integrate[q[x], {x, 0, L1}] + Integrate[f[t]*q[x], {x, 0, L1}]
```

Just wanted to point the problem more clearly that is all.

**Edit**

Additional observation.  It seems the simplification does not happen becuase Mathematica does not know that `f[x]` does not depend implicitly on `t`. See:

```
Clear[x,t,f,g,L1]
Integrate[x*g[t],{x,0,L1}]-g[t]*Integrate[x,{x,0,L1}]

Out[14]= 0
```

Becuase it now sees that `f[x]` really does NOT really depend on `t`, then it pulled out `g[t]` and we get zero.

But when we write

```
 Clear[x, t, f, g, L1]
 Integrate[f[x]*g[t], {x, 0, L1}] - g[t]*Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, L1}]

 Out[17]= (-g[t])*Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, L1}] + Integrate[f[x]*g[t], {x, 0, L1}]
```

So, may be some assumptions is needed. Not sure now. Just thought to mention this.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the trick [@Jens showed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5611/193). See his post (and upvote it!) for an explanation:

```
fec /: Integrate[fec[x_], x_] := Intfec[x];
SetAttributes[Intfec, {NumericFunction}];

inta = Cos[q3[t]] fec[x] q5[t]^2 D[q3[t], t]^2;
a = Integrate[inta, {x, 0, L1}];

b1 = Cos[q3[t]] q5[t]^2 D[q3[t], t]^2;
b = Integrate[fec[x], {x, 0, L1}] b1;

a - b
(*
-> 0
*)
```

Comment: Dear Verde,
Thanks for your help, and now my problem has been resolved.

Comment: I edited your answer to add a fix for version 10 that I also used in the answer you linked to.

Comment: @Jens Thanks! No v10 here yet, unable to test :(