# Integral of the derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In `11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018`) writing:

```
Integrate[D[x*Sqrt[f[x]], x], x]
```

I would expect:

> x*Sqrt[f[x]]

instead MMA fails to integrate.

Do I miss something?

Comment: `Integrate` internal code simply fails to recognize that the integrand is an exact derivative.

Comment: I think it comes down to simply evaluation order. Mathematica evaluates the derivative first then looks at the result.  It does not have a build-in rule for Integrate[D[f[x],x],x]-> f[x]. I do not how to tell Mathematica not to evaluate the derivative first before trying to integrate the result.  I tried this in Maple, and Maple seems to have such a rule build it. Screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PEXSI.png)  btw, here is related question [integrate-full-derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66494/integrate-full-derivative)