# A simple integral operation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Evaluating the following expression results in a non-zero output

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[2 f[x], {x,0,1}] - 2 Integrate[f[x], {x,0,1}]]
```

I think the output should be zero, but do not know how to simplify this expression. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Welcome!  Without the actual definition for *f[x]*, *Mathematica* will not be able to evaluate the expression.

Comment: Interestingly, `Integrate[2*f[x] - 2*f[x], {x, 0, 1}]` is evaluated to `0`, even without a definition for `f[x]`.

Comment: Obviously, you did not give any attention at the expression. The definition for f is not needed. The above quantity MUST be zero. It is more than trivial. Mathematica does not simplify the expression and the question is "why"?

Answer (score 3):

Use the Jens trick:

```
f /: Integrate[f[x_], x_] := if[x];
SetAttributes[if, {NumericFunction}];
```

And now

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[2 f[x], {x, 0, 1}] - 2 Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]]

(* 0 *)
```

You can read more about this in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5610/how-to-simplify-symbolic-integration/5611#5611)

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case:

```
(Integrate[2 f[x], {x,0,1}] - 2 Integrate[f[x], {x,0,1}]) /. (Integrate[x_*f[h_], z_]) :> x* Integrate[f[h], z]
```