# Solve differential equation using a integral form boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

I have a second order differential equation and I want to solve it analytically (`DSolve`) and numerically (`NDSolve`) with following boundary conditions.

```
y''[x] - y[x] == (x^2)
```

Boundary conditions:

```
y[0] == 1
Integrate[y[x], {x, 0, 2}] == 5
```

How can I implement an integral form boundary condition for solving this differential equation?

Comment: First look at `DSolve` in the help menus. I think it would be easiest to get the analytic expression for `y[x]` first, `Integrate` the resulting expression from 0 to 2, then `Solve` the set of simultaneous equations (your boundary conditions) for `C[1]` and `C[2]`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
s = DSolveValue[{y''[x] - y[x] == (x^2), y[0] == 1}, y[x], x];
First@Solve[Integrate[s, {x, 0, 2}] == 5, C[1]];
s /. %
{*  E^-x (3 - 2 E^x - (9 + 26 E^2)/(3 (-1 + E^2)^2) + (E^(2 x) (9 + 26 E^2))/
    (3 (-1 + E^2)^2) - E^x x^2) *}
```

**Alternative solution**

The answer by Karsten7 suggests the following: With `y[x]` replaced by `g'[x]`,

```
D[DSolveValue[{g'''[x] - g'[x] == x^2, g'[0] == 1, g[2] - g[0] == 5}, 
   g[x], x], x] // Simplify
```

which gives the same result as above.

[image]

**Addendum**

A numerical solution, as request by the OP in a comment, can be obtained from the second solution above by replacing `DSolveValue` by `NDSolveValue` and assigning a value to `g[0]`.  (Any value will do, because the subsequent differentiation eliminates it.)

```
s = NDSolveValue[{g'''[x] - g'[x] == x^2, g[0] == 0, g'[0] == 1, g[2] - g[0] == 5}, g', x]
```

which gives a curve identical to the one obtained previously.

Comment: I saw your comment asking for an `NDSolve` solution only now.  (Because you attached the comment to Karsten7's answer, it went only to him.)  I have added a solution closely patterned after my second `DSolve` solution.  In fact, the two can be written so that they differ only by the substitution of `NDSolve` for `DSolve.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 15):

### Analytical Solution

A corrected version of the now deleted answer by [Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser), that uses a trick explained in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5611/245) by [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens):

```
Clear[f, if, y, x, g];
f /: Integrate[f[x_], x_] := if[x];
SetAttributes[if, {NumericFunction}];
sol = Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2}];
bc2 = sol == 5 /. if -> g
```

> ```
> -g[0] + g[2] == 5
> ```

With `g` beeing the antiderivative of `y`.

```
ode = g'''[x] - g'[x] == (x^2);
bc1 = g'[0] == 1;
sol = g[x] /. First@DSolve[{ode, bc1, bc2}, g[x], x]

y1[x_] = D[sol, x] // FullSimplify  (* y[x]=g'[x] *)
```

> ```
> 1/3 ((E^-x (E^2 (-44 + 9 E^2) + E^(2 x) (9 + 26 E^2)))/(-1 + E^2)^2 - 3 (2 + x^2))
> ```

---

### Numerical Solution

```
sol2[bc2_, {xmin_, xmax_}] := 
 NDSolveValue[{y''[x] - y[x] == (x^2), y'[0] == bc2, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, xmin, xmax}];
int[bc2_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[sol2[bc2, {0, 2}][x], {x, 0, 2}];
y2 = sol2[NMinimize[(int[bc2V] - 5)^2, bc2V][[-1, -1, -1]], {-3, 3}]

Plot[{y1[x], y2[x]}, {x, -3, 3}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Ok, I agree Mathematica result from my method is not correct, but my question is, what did I do wrong? where in the steps I did the error was?

Comment: @Nasser I hope my edit makes it more clear, that you changed from `y` being the original function to `y` being the antiderivative of the original function in the first part, but didn't make that change in the second part, and therefore missed to take the derivative.

Comment: I think the reference that @Nasser was starting with is [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5611/245).

Comment: Thanks guys. These are the answers are related to DSolve. What about NDSolve?? Assume that there is non-homogeneous second order differential equation with the same boundary condition (y''[x] - Cos[x] y[x] == x^2). Please help me on that, too

Comment: @Emad I added one way to find the solution numerically.

Comment: @Karsten7, may I continue this topic, can we also solve 4th order problem (analytical or numerical)?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM One can solve fourth-order ODE's (see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DifferentialEquations.html#6193 & https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveClassificationOfDifferentialEquations.html). You should try to do so yourself and ask a new question if you get stucked. But there is no continuation here.