# Inhomogeneous Heat Equation Formula Not Satisfying IVP

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, heat-equation

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Inhomogeneous_heat_equation),

[image: t]

However, when I plug the formula of $u(x,t)$ into Mathematica 12.1, it doesn't seem to satisfy the PDE (does not give $0$):

[image]

Here is the code:

```
G[x_, t_] := 1/Sqrt[4*Pi*k*t]*Exp[-x^2/(4*k*t)]

u[x_, t_] := Integrate[G[x - y, t - s]*f[y, s], {s, 0, t}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]

FullSimplify[D[u[x, t], t] - k*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - f[x, t], Assumptions -> t > 0 && k > 0]
```

Comment: btw, you need to also add `k>0` if you are going to do it this way, but this does not help with the integration part there. also on V 12.1 I get no `Indeterminate` in the result, just unevaluated integrals. You might want to double check the Green function you used again just in case.

Comment: I checked that the formula is correct.

Comment: The definition of `u` should be `Integrate[G[x - y, t - s]*f[y, s], {s, 0, t}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]` We cannot arbitrarily interchange the order of integration in this case. (This doesn't help solving the problem, though. )

Comment: @xzczd TIL the order of ```Integrate``` is the opposite. The documentation doesn't have a clear example for multiple integration.

Comment: I guess this design is for keeping consistent with `Table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to extend my comment to an answer. As mentioned above, OP's attempt fails mainly because `D` calculates based on [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) but sadly this rule doesn't apply in this case, because the integrand is no longer continuous when $s=t$.

Still, we can verify the solution using *Mathematica*, with a little manual analysis. First of all, we introduce a **positive** $\epsilon$ to the solution:

$$u(x,t)=\int_{0}^{t-\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k(t-s)}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4k(t-s)}\right)f(y,s)\,dy\,ds$$

```
G[x_, t_] := Exp[-x^2/(4 k t)]/Sqrt[4 π k t]

u[x_, t_] := Integrate[G[x - y, t - s] f[y, s], {s, 0, t - ϵ}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Substitute it back to the equation:

```
residual = D[u[x, t], t] - k D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - f[x, t] // Simplify // Expand
```

[image]

It's easy to notice the last 2 terms cancel. We can manually delete them from the output, but here I'll do it programatically to make the answer more interesting:

```
residual2 = 
 With[{int = Integrate}, 
  residual //. 
   HoldPattern[
     coef1_ int[expr1_, rest_] + coef2_ int[expr2_, rest_]] :> 
    int[coef1 expr1 + coef2 expr2, rest]]
```

[image]

**Remark**

> 1. In *v9.0.1* the following is enough:
>
>    ```
>    residual2 = With[{int = Integrate}, 
>     residual /. 
>      HoldPattern[coef_ int[int[expr_,rest1_],rest2_]]:>int[coef expr, rest2, rest1]]
>    (*
>    -f[x, t] + Integrate[(k f[y, t - ϵ])/(E^((x - y)^2/(4 k ϵ)) Sqrt[k ϵ]), 
>                         {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]/(2 k Sqrt[Pi])
>    *)
>    ```
> 2. [`moveconst`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5620/1871) can
>      be used in *v9.0.1* in the following manner but it's a bit slow:
>
>    ```
>    residual2 = FullSimplify[D[u[x, t], t] - k D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - f[x, t], 
>      TransformationFunctions -> {moveconst, Automatic}]
>    ```

We know (from e.g. [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)) one possible defintion for Dirac delta is

$$
\delta_a(x)=\frac{1}{|a|\sqrt \pi}e^{-(x/a)^2}\ \text{as}\ a\to 0
$$

So the `… Exp[-(…)^2]` can be replaced with a `… DiracDelta[…]` when $\epsilon \to 0$.

It's a pity that `Limit` won't help in this case, as mentioned in the **Possible Issues** section of document of `DiracDelta`. Once again, it's not a bad idea to modify the output by hand, but I'll replace by coding to make the answer more interesting:

```
residual3 = 
 Assuming[{x ∈ Reals, ϵ > 0, k > 0}, 
  residual2 /. Exp[coef_ a_^2] :> DiracDelta[a]/Sqrt[-coef] Sqrt[Pi]]

(* -f[x, t] + f[x, t - ϵ] *)

residual3 /. ϵ -> 0
(* 0 *)
```

As we can see, all terms in the equation cancel, the solution is verified. (Verification for the initial condition is trivial. )

Tested in *v9.0.1*, *v12.0.1*, *v12.1.0*.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Mathematica is correct

```
Clear["Global`*"]
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == k D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + f[x, t];
ic = u[x, 0] == 0;
sol = DSolve[{pde, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t}];
sol /. {K[1] -> y, K[2] -> s}
```

$$
\left\{\left\{u(x,t)\to \frac{\int _0^t\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\sqrt{\frac{k}{t-s}} f(y,s)
   e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4 k (t-s)}}dyds}{2 \sqrt{\pi } k}\right\}\right\}
$$

Which is the same as one you show

[image]

### Verfication

The hint below given by xzczd made me think that if $f(x,t)$ was given, i.e. a specific function, then Mathematica should be able to verify the book solution.

And this is indeed the case. Tried few random `$f(x,t)` and Mathematica can verify it now, giving `True`. It does take few seconds to do, depending how complicated $f(x,t)$ is.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
```

`moveconst` is from [how to simplify symbolic integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5610/how-to-simplify-symbolic-integration)  thanks to celtschk

```
moveconst[
   x_] := (x /. 
    Integrate[factor_ expr_, {var_, min_, max_}] /; 
      FreeQ[factor, var] :> factor Integrate[expr, {var, min, max}]);

pde = D[u[x, t], t] == k*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + f[x, t];
G[x_, t_] := 1/Sqrt[4*Pi*k*t]*Exp[-x^2/(4*k*t)];
bookAnswer = 
  Integrate[G[x - y, t]*g[y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}] + 
   Integrate[
    G[x - y, t - s]*f[y, s], {s, 0, t}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}];
f[x_, t_] := x*t;
sol = u -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate@bookAnswer];
result = pde /. sol;
Simplify[result, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, moveconst}]

(*True*)
```

Tried `f[x_, t_] := Sin[t]*x;` and few others, all give `True`.

Comment: Thanks, but why is Mathematica unable to verify it by substitution though?

Comment: @Leponzo Because [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @xzczd That was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @Leponzo added verification

Answer (score 0):

k must be both real and positive for the given domain. f[x,t] has to be well foldable as well on the domain `Reals` x positive `Reals`.

See [convolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Convolve.html) for the corresponding built-in in Mathematica.

Some theory can be found: [convolution](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/Mathematica/ch6/convolution.html).

This book offers some more detail: [Introduction to Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers using Mathematica](https://books.google.de/books?id=fTvSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR10&lpg=PR10&dq=convolution%20mathematica%20heat&source=bl&ots=BSk1Qu-NS_&sig=ACfU3U2TohSb9RdJw4fSEzj2x9CtBboGzw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjm-YHNy-3pAhWJCuwKHXydD5gQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=convolution%20mathematica%20heat&f=false). It is from 2014 and so fairly modern. It offers a convolution theorem in chapter 2 Integral transforms.

[Handout for convolution on heat equations](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/heateqn.pdf) from Stanford University.

Comment: Can you show what you mean by using convolve? It would be best if you included code. Link-only answers become useless when the links invariably break at some point in the future.