Solving ODE with DiracDelta on the right-hand side
I want to use Mathematica to validate the solution to this differential equation
$ (E+ \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\kappa x)G(x,y) = i \hbar  \delta(x-y)   $
The solution is supposed to be
$$ G(x,y)=-\frac{4 i m \sqrt{\left(x-\frac{e}{\kappa }\right) \left(y-\frac{e}{\kappa }\right)} K_{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2}
   \left(x-\frac{e}{\kappa }\right)^{3/2} \sqrt{m \kappa }}{3 \hbar }\right) I_{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \left(y-\frac{e}{\kappa
   }\right)^{3/2} \sqrt{m \kappa }}{3 \hbar }\right)}{3 \hbar } $$
where $ K $ and $I$ are modfified Bessel functions. When I put in the following code:
FullSimplify[e*g + \[HBar]^2/(2*m)*D[g, {x, 2}] - \[Kappa]*x*g]
(where $g = G(x,y)$ from above), Mathematica returns $0$ as the answer. Is there any way to get Mathematica to give $i \hbar \delta(x-y)$ as the output?
Edit: The Mathematica code for g is
g = (-4*I*m)/(3*\[HBar])*Sqrt[(x - e/\[Kappa])*(y - e/\[Kappa])]*(BesselK[1/3, 
   Sqrt[8*m*\[Kappa]]/(3*\[HBar])*(x - e/\[Kappa])^(3/2)])*(BesselI[1/
   3, Sqrt[8*m*\[Kappa]]/(3*\[HBar])*(y - e/\[Kappa])^(3/2)]) 
                                                          

It seems that when I put in:
FullSimplify[e*g + (\[HBar]^2/(2*m))*D[g, {x, 2}] - \[Kappa]*x*g == I*\[HBar]*DiracDelta[x - y], Assumptions -> x > y]  

or
FullSimplify[e*g + (\[HBar]^2/(2*m))*D[g, {x, 2}] - \[Kappa]*x*g == I*\[HBar]*DiracDelta[x - y], Assumptions -> x < y]

Mathematica returns True.

Mathematica returns answers that are generally true, which in this case effectively means that it evaluates the left-hand side, which is zero every where it's defined (i.e., away from $x=y$). I'm not sure if you're going to be able to get it spit out a Dirac delta here.


Please show us the Mathematica code for $G(x,y)$, too. 2. Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/223575/1871


I think it is hopeless because the MMA result of D[Abs[x], {x, 2}] is simply Abs''[x].

@usernew76 Have a look at GreenFunction!

@xzczd I have added the Mathematica code for $ G(x,y) $.

The command of Maple 2024 dsolve(e*g(x) + h^2/(2*m)*diff(g(x), x, x) - k*x*g(x) = h*Dirac(x - y)*I) produces

g(x) = AiryAi((-2*k*m/h^2)^(1/3)*(-k*x+e)/k)*c__2+AiryBi((-2*k*m/h^2)^(1/3)*(-k *x+e)/k)*c__1-I*Heaviside(-x+y)*2^(2/3)*Pi*m*(AiryBi(2^(1/3)*(-k*m/h^2)^(1/3)*( -k*y+e)/k)*AiryAi(2^(1/3)*(-k*m/h^2)^(1/3)*(-k*x+e)/k)-AiryAi(2^(1/3)*(-k*m/h^2 )^(1/3)*(-k*y+e)/k)*AiryBi(2^(1/3)*(-k*m/h^2)^(1/3)*(-k*x+e)/k))/h/(-k*m/h^2)^( 1/3). Mathematica 14.1 fails with it.

The command of Maple 2024 odetest(g(x) = AiryAi((-2*k*m/h^2)^(1/3)*(-k*x+e)/k)*c__2+AiryBi((-2*k*m/h^2)^(1/3)*(-k *x+e)/k)*c__1-I*Heaviside(-x+y)*2^(2/3)*Pi*m*(AiryBi(2^(1/3)*(-k*m/h^2)^(1/3)*( -k*y+e)/k)*AiryAi(2^(1/3)*(-k*m/h^2)^(1/3)*(-k*x+e)/k)-AiryAi(2^(1/3)*(-k*m/h^2 )^(1/3)*(-k*y+e)/k)*AiryBi(2^(1/3)*(-k*m/h^2)^(1/3)*(-k*x+e)/k))/h/(-k*m/h^2)^( 1/3),e*g(x)+h^2/(2*m)*diff(g(x),x$2)-k*x*g(x)=h*Dirac(x-y)*I); results in 0, confirming the solution.

Your solution g fullfills the homogenous ode
g = Function[
  x, (-4*I*m)/(3*\[HBar])*
   Sqrt[(x - e/\[Kappa])*(y - e/\[Kappa])]*(BesselK[1/3, 
        Sqrt[
        8*m*\[Kappa]]/(3*\[HBar])*(x - e/\[Kappa])^(3/2)])*(BesselI[1/
         3, Sqrt[8*m*\[Kappa]]/(3*\[HBar])*(y - e/\[Kappa])^(3/2)]) ]
e*g[x] + \[HBar]^2/(2*m)* g''[x] - \[Kappa]*x*g[x] // FullSimplify
(* 0*)

g is also a solution of the inhomogenous ode if AsymptoticIntegrate[ e*g[x] + \[HBar]^2/(2*m)* g''[x] - \[Kappa]*x*g[x], {x, y - eps,  y + eps}, eps -> 0]==I h
Asymptotic integration is approximated by zw0+zw1
    zw0 = Asymptotic[
   eps (e*g[x] - \[Kappa]*x*g[x] /. x -> y + eps) + 
    0 (e*g[x] - \[Kappa]*x*g[x] /. x -> y - eps), {eps, 0, 1}] // 
  FullSimplify

Here we assume because of causality g[x,x-eps]==0
zw1 = Asymptotic[\[HBar]^2/(2*m)* (g'[y + eps ] - g'[y - eps ]),eps -> 0] // FullSimplify

Asymptotic[zw1 + zw0 - I h, eps -> 0]  (* -I h*)

It looks like function g is the solution of the ode e*g[x] + \[HBar]^2/(2*m)* g''[x] - \[Kappa]*x*g[x]==- I h DiracDelta[x-y]!
Except for the sign that's QP's expectation!
Hope it helps!

Mathematica 14 yields a page of a result that can be simplified by the assumptions
   $Assumptions = {W, m, \[HBar], \[Kappa], x, y} > 0 && 
       x  > W/\[Kappa] && y  > W/\[Kappa]

justified by atomic units $\hbar=m=1$ and parameters for free waves.
G = Function[{x, y, W, \[Kappa]}, (-4*I*m)/(3*\[HBar])*
Sqrt[(x - W/\[Kappa])*(y - W/\[Kappa])]*
(BesselK[1/3, 
   Sqrt[8*m*\[Kappa]]/(3*\[HBar])*(x - W/\[Kappa])^(3/ 2)])*
    (BesselI[1/3, 
  Sqrt[8*m*\[Kappa]]/(3*\[HBar])*(y - W/\[Kappa])^(3/2)])]; 

   ((W - \[Kappa] x) # + 1/(2 m) \[HBar]^2 D[#,x,x] # &)[ G[x, y]] // 
  PowerExpand // FunctionExpand // Simplify // 
    PowerExpand // FullSimplify


 ((W - \[Kappa] x) # + \[HBar]^2/(2 m) D[#,x,x] &)[
      G[x, y, W, \[Kappa]]] // FullSimplify

 0

The function G in $\mathbb C : x+i z$ has complex branch lines, that evaluate to a plane of discontinuity between wave solutions and exponential solution in the $(x,y,G)$ space.
In atomic units
H = Function[{x,y,W,\[Kappa]},-((4*I)/3)*
Sqrt[(x-W/\[Kappa])*(y -W/ \[Kappa])]*
 (BesselK[1/3,Sqrt[8*\[Kappa]]/3*(x-W/\[Kappa])^(3/2)])*
 (BesselI[1/3,Sqrt[8*\[Kappa]]/3*(y-W/\[Kappa])^(3/2)])]


Show[{Plot3D[
 Evaluate[ReIm@H[x, y + 0.02 I, 1., 2]], 
       {x, -4, 4}, {y, -2, 2}, 
         PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0.2], Blue}, {Opacity[0.8], Red}}], 
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], 
     InfinitePlane[{1/2, 0, 0}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}]}]


All Greens functions of wave equations are Schwarz distributions as boundary values of analytic functions  Bremerman
