# help on simplification with integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

V 12.1

How can one help Mathematica obtain zero for the following expression, by telling it that $k$ is really just a constant?

$$
k \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(x) \, dx-\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } k f(x) \, dx
$$

When we do the above by hand, clearly it is zero, because we pull constant out of the integral.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[ 
k Integrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]-Integrate[k f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], 
     Assumptions -> {k > 0, Element[k, Reals]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(note, `Element[k, Reals]` is not really needed, since `k>0` implies `k` is real.

Reduce does not do it either.

Fyi, Maple 2020:

```
restart;
simplify( k*int(f(x),x=-infinity..infinity) - int( k *f(x),x=-infinity..infinity) )
                               0
```

Comment: It simplifies to `0` for the indefinite integrals `k Integrate[f[x], x] - Integrate[k f[x], x]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, I noticed that also. I think it should simplify to zero for both cases.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found answer, thanks to [how to simplify symbolic integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5610/how-to-simplify-symbolic-integration)

Using the function `moveconst` given in the above thanks to celtschk

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
moveconst[x_] := (x /. 
    Integrate[factor_ expr_, {var_, min_, max_}] /; 
      FreeQ[factor, var] :> factor Integrate[expr, {var, min, max}]);
```

And now

```
Simplify[k Integrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] - 
  Integrate[k f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, moveconst}]

 (* 0 *)
```

I am still not sure why this is needed, as `k` is clearly undefined symbol and hence does not depend on `f[x]`. But this is what is needed in Mathematica to get zero.