# Assume that the value of an integral is real

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, integral-transforms

I would like to give a condition that the integral I am handling are not complexes.

Consider

```
$Assumptions=Element[a,Reals] && Element[b,Reals] && Element[t,Reals] && Element[f[t],Reals] && Element[R,Reals] && Element[Integrate[b f[t],{t,-R,R}],Reals]

ep = a + I b;

B=Integrate[ComplexExpand[f[t] ep],{t,-R,R}] // Distribute

Re[B] //Distribute
```

The output is:

```
Re[Integrate[a f[t], {t, -R, R}]] + Re[Integrate[I b f[t], {t, -R, R}]]
```

I think that is can't simplify because it may happen that the value of the integral (even if the integrand is real) is complex, how can I tell mathematica to give the result : `Integrate[a f[t], {t, -R, R}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at what happens if we factor the `ep` term out of the integral, like this

```
ClearAll[a, b, f, R, t]

ep = a + I b;

B = Integrate[f[t] , {t, -R, R}] ep;

With[{$Assumptions = Element[Integrate[ f[t], {t, -R, R}], Reals]},
 Re[B] // ComplexExpand // Simplify
 ]

(*   a*Integrate[f[t], {t, -R, R}]   *)
```

So, it looks like MMA is able to apply the assumption that the integral is real.  Note that we used `With` to make a temporary change to the global `$Assumptions` and we applied the assumptions using `Simplify`.  (The `Simplify` takes about 12 seconds on my desktop.  I wonder why.)

Next, we start with the `ep` term inside the integral.  This time we will use `With` to set the `$Assumptions` and to factor `ep`, or any other contants, out of the integral, like this

```
ClearAll[a, b, f, R, t]

ep = a + I b;

B = Integrate[f[t] ep, {t, -R, R}]

With[{$Assumptions = Im@Integrate[ f[t], {t, -R, R}] == 0,
  B = B //.
    Integrate[q1___ r__ q2___, {v_, s___}] /; FreeQ[{r}, v] :>
     r Integrate[q1 q2, {v, s}]},
 
 (Re[B] // ComplexExpand // Simplify) /.
  Times[r_, Integrate[q_, {v_, s___}]] /; FreeQ[{r}, v] :> 
   Integrate[r q, {v, s}]
 ]

(*   Integrate[a*f[t], {t, -R, R}]   *)
```

Note the different, but equivalent, assumptions in the two `With` statements.  Also note that factoring the constants out of the integral is done with code provided by @dr-belisarius in his answer to [How to do algebra on unevaluated integrals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64422/how-to-do-algebra-on-unevaluated-integrals/64447#64447).  Another reference that may be useful is [How to simplify symbolic integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5610/how-to-simplify-symbolic-integration).